# Vuex pass mutable object as prop, call mutation with the passed object as argument

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

Let's say I have a Vuex State which contains an array of objects which I want to mutate in the component. I iterate over the array and spawn a Component for each Object which takes the Object as a prop. Inside the component I call Vuex mutations with the Object passed down as a direct argument. For example:

Parent

```vue
<template>
    <ItemComponent
        v-for="(item, index) in items"
        :key="index"
        :index="index"
        :item="item"
    />
</template>

<script>
import ItemComponent from 'ItemComponent.vue';

export default {
    components: {
        ItemComponent
    },
    computed: {
        items() {
            return this.$store.getters.items;
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Child:

```vue
<template>

</template>

<script>

export default {
    props: {
        item: {
            type: Object,
            required: true
        }
    },
    methods: {
        changeItemProp() {
            this.$store.dispatch('changeItemXValue', {this.item, 'newValue'});
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Store:

```js
// ...
mutations: {
  changeItemXValue(state, { item, value }) {
    item.x = value
  }
}
```

It works, yes. But I'm pretty sure this is an Antipattern, right?

```js
// ...
mutations: {
  changeItemXValue(state, { item, value }) {
    state.items.find((i) => i === item).x = value
  }
}
```

This doesn't seem much better.

My question: Is this the way to go if I want to encapsulate my mutable data in a subcomponent, or is this considered an anti-pattern? In which case I would like to know what the proper way is to handle this case. I initially prepared vuex exactly to handle this case but I'm not sure if this is quite the right way. Thank you.

Comment: Instead of passing the item itself to the mutation, pass an item ID (e.g., its index). Then your mutation could lookup the item (which could also be more performant than `find`) to set its value.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are multiple ways of doing this, but I'll explain a recommended way of doing.
What you're doing right now is that, you're fetching items from store, passing them to a child component (By iteration) then mutating following mutation,

```
// ...
mutations: {
  changeItemXValue(state, { item, value }) {
    state.items.find((i) => i === item).x = value
  }
}
```

First of all, you don't need to mutate this item directly, instead you should create an action that finds the item for you and then mutate it using item id or index. 
So what you need to do is that, create an action, when changing value of item, dispatch that action, and pass item id or even item to that action. Inside that action, find the item you want to mutate and then commit mutation, inside your mutation, simply write

```
state.items[itemIndex] = newValue
```